# What spells can an Arcane Trickster Rogue choose from when gaining levels?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rogue

Trying to understand how an Arcane Trickster Rogue works with regards to spell selection. In the Player's Handbook, page 98, it says (emphasis mine):

> You know three 1st-level wizard spells of your choice, **two** of which you must choose from the enchantment and illusion spells on the wizard spell list.

Then it goes on to say:

> The spells known column of the arcane trickster spell casting table shows when you learn more wizard spells of 1st level or higher. **Each of these spells** must be either an enchantment or illusion spell of your choice.

Can I have spells of the other types starting at level 3 or not?

If I can only cast spells from any school at 8th level, what are the acceptable types of spells that I start out with (besides *mage hand*)?

Comment: Isn't the answer in your question?

Comment: I'm stuck with the exact same problem. How come nobody can see the problem with the Player's Handbook? There is a clear contradiction, albeit you didn't emphasise it 100% correctly.

Answer (score 11):

The Arcane Trickster rogue's **Spellcasting** feature says:

> When you reach 3rd level, you gain the ability to cast spells. See Chapter 10 for the general rules of spellcasting and chapter 11 for the *wizard spell list*. (5e PHB p. 98, emphasis mine)

The arcane trickster (generally) chooses from the **Wizard** spell list, inferred from above, and generally must make those choices from the enchantment or illusion schools. There are exceptions, both to the school-limitation and to the wizard-limitation:

1. ***Cantrips.*** Two of your starting cantrips and the cantrip you learn at 10th level must come from the *wizard list* but are *not restricted by school*.
2. ***Leveled Spells.*** One of the leveled spells you learn at 3rd level and the single leveled spell you learn at each of 8th, 14th, & 20th level must come from the *wizard list* but are *not restricted by school*.
3. At 17th level you become a **Spell Thief** and "can steal the knowledge of how to cast a spell from another spellcaster. (*Ibid.*)" So these spells are *not restricted to the wizard list.*

So the spells you're choosing at leveling-up are always from the wizard list, mostly enchantments and illusions. But you can *steal* a spell from any list.

Comment: I didn't read the question as being about picking non-wizard spells, but about picking non-enchantment/illusion spells.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the breakdown of what you need to know:

- At 3rd level: 2 spells from any combination of the Enchantment and
  Illusion schools, plus 1 spell from any school.
- 4th through 6th levels: 3 spells from combo of Enchantment and
  Illusion schools, plus 1 spell from any school.
- 7th level: 4 spells from combo of Enchantment and Illusion schools,
  plus 1 spell from any school.
- 8th through 9th levels: 4 spells from combo of Enchantment and
  Illusion schools, plus 2 spells from any school.
- 10th level: 5 spells from combo of Enchantment and Illusion schools,
  plus 2 spells from any school.
- 11th through 12th levels: 6 spells from combo of Enchantment and
  Illusion schools, plus 2 spells from any school.
- 13th level: 7 spells from combo of Enchantment and Illusion schools,
  plus 2 spells from any school.
- 14th through 15th levels: 7 spells combo, plus any 3 spells from any
  spell.
- 16th through 18th levels: 8 spells combo, plus any 3 spells from any
  school.
- 19th level: 9 from combo, and 3 spells from any school.
- 20th level: 9 spells combo, plus 4 spells from any school.